# Cannot run React-Native app on Android emulator - Windows

Tags: android, react-native, emulation

I tried running react-native run-android while my emulator was running but it throws this error:

> Skipping device 'Nexus_5X_API_28(AVD) - 9' for 'app:debug': Could not find build of variant which supports density 420 and an ABI in x86

I tried to google it but most of the answers were too old and did not work. I tried the adb reverse but still it fails.

Comment: try creating a newer emulator

Comment: @Vencovsky I did that, and still shows the same error eventhough the new emulator has density of 420 and ABI in x86x

Answer (score 7):

Module:Check out build.gradle from app. There are the following configurations:

```
 ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64', 'x86' 
    }
```

This will work for you. I tried on React-native-android.

Comment: have to add in default config and inside splits in abi as well

Comment: I tried to use this way. But not work for me.

Comment: ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64', 'x86'
        }

Comment: Not working, throwing; Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeDebug[x86]'. when i add 'x86' in abiFilters

Answer (score 3):

As @hong-developer mentioned, adding the `"x86"` worked for me.

Go to your  `project\android\app\build.gradle`

then:

```
...
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false
        include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64", "x86"
    }
}
...
```

Comment: worked ... but you have to add these in default config as well !! Change the answer and i will accept it